# Drag and Drop C# (Unity 2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I am a newbie Unity dev and am making a game that involves a drag and drop system, I watched a tutorial and got help from a friend but it won't work... an error I get is it says public isn't valid or what ever, same for private.

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour
{
Vector2 difference = Vector2.zero;
}
private void OnMouseDown()
{
difference = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
}
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
transform.position = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - difference;
}
```

[here is a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGDaS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are written outside the class. Correct the parentheses.

```cs
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 difference = Vector2.zero;
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        transform.position = (Vector2) Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - difference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to test this out!

Comment: @Explorer you're welcome. Of course, I doubt that the logic you wrote for Drag & Drop will work correctly.

Comment: Idk much about the logic, I just followed a tutorial from YT, also could you kinda explain what this error means? I might be able to fix it. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/853786155963514915/1012165802759307366/unknown.png

Comment: @Explorer In the OnMouseDown function, transform.position is of Vector3 type, which cannot be subtracted with cast mouseRay. Remove the transformation (Vector2) from the beginning of the line as in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Methods are outside the scope of the class, ensure of move then into the body of your class inside the block "{ }"

Comment: Thanks man! Gonna try to remember this later!!